How to get data from room database by using month?
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM purchased_products WHERE strftime('%m', purchased_date / 1000) = :month")
LiveData<List<PurchasedItems>> getPurchasedItemByMonth(int month);

I give the current month and want to retrieve everything under that month.

Update room Query
    @Query(value = """
    SELECT * 
    FROM purchased_products
    WHERE strftime('%m', purchased_date, 'unixepoch') = :month
""")
LiveData<List<PurchasedProduct>> getPurchasedItemByMonth(String month)

get Data from the database
val currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 // Months are 0-indexed
val formattedMonth = String.format("%02d", currentMonth) // Ensure leading zero

viewModel.getPurchasedItemByMonth(formattedMonth).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { purchasedItems ->
}


The strftime function, like ALL the date and time functions will only work on recognised formats.
IF, as it appears,  you have stored a unix timestamp (the clue being the division by 1000) then you have to tell the function that is the format to distinguish it from a Julian value. As such it would  appear that you need to specify the unixepoch modifier.
So possibly (but see However below):-
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM purchased_products WHERE strftime('%m', purchased_date / 1000,'unixepoch') = :month") LiveData<List> getPurchasedItemByMonth(int month);

AS per https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#modifiers (18)

Note this is very much an answer based upon assumptions as the question lacks actual underlying values
the link goes directly to the modifiers, you may wish to consider the entire document.
especially note The "unixepoch" modifier (18) only works if it immediately follows a time value in the DDDDDDDDDD format. i.e. it's position is critical.
that month, would be irrespective of the year
you could (would normally) just have @Query("SELECT * FROM purchased_products WHERE strftime('%m', purchased_date / 1000,'unixepoch') = :month") LiveData<List> getPurchasedItemByMonth(int month);

However
You will very likely have an issue in that the parameter passed will be an INTEGER value 1,2 .... 12 whilst the value extracted by %m will be a TEXT value. As such 1 = 01 will be false.
To overcome this issue, you could CAST the TEXT value to an INTEGER value so:-
@Query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE CAST(strftime('%m',d1 / 1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER)=:month" )


Demo

Consider the following class (as it's annotated with @Entity then the SQlite table Thetable):-
@Entity
class TheTable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    private Long d1;

    TheTable() {
        this.id=null;
        this.d1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    TheTable(Long id,long d1) {
        this.id = id;
        this.d1 = d1;
    }
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getD1() {
        return d1;
    }

    public void setD1(Long d1) {
        this.d1 = d1;
    }

    public void logIt(String tag, String tag_suffix) {
        String d2 = sdf.format(new Date(d1));
        Log.d(tag + tag_suffix,"ID is " + id + " D1 is " + d1 + " D1(formatted) is " + d2);
    }
}


should matter that it's Java as it's a simple 2 column table an id column that will typically be a value that is generated and a d1 column that will store the/a timestamp.

The consider the following @Dao annotated abstract class (close to an interface but allows methods with bodies (not reqd in this demo but habitually used)):-
@Dao
abstract class AllDAOs {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(TheTable t);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE strftime('%m',d1 / 1000)=:month" )
    abstract List<TheTable> getByMonthNumberOriginal(int month);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE CAST(strftime('%m',d1 / 1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER)=:month" )
    abstract List<TheTable> getByMonthNumber(int month);
}

And the following activity code that will insert 3 rows (one a year in the future) and then use the query as per the question and then the query as per the answer and write the resultant data to the log for each of the 12 months:-
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAOs dao;
    private static final String TAG = "DBINFO";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDAOs();

        dao.insert(new TheTable());
        dao.insert(new TheTable(null,System.currentTimeMillis()+ 100000));
        dao.insert(new TheTable(null,System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 365L) /* a year later */));
        for(int m=1; m < 13; m++) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Processing Month " + m);
            for (TheTable t: dao.getByMonthNumberOriginal(m)) {
                t.logIt(TAG,"_MNTH" + m);
            }
        }
        for(int m=1; m < 13; m++) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Processing Month " + m);
            for (TheTable t: dao.getByMonthNumber(m)) {
                t.logIt(TAG,"_MNTH" + m);
            }
        }
    }
}

The log, for such a run:-
2024-05-22 14:52:37.251 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 1
2024-05-22 14:52:37.258 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 2
2024-05-22 14:52:37.260 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 3
2024-05-22 14:52:37.261 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 4
2024-05-22 14:52:37.262 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 5
2024-05-22 14:52:37.262 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 6
2024-05-22 14:52:37.263 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 7
2024-05-22 14:52:37.263 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 8
2024-05-22 14:52:37.264 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 9
2024-05-22 14:52:37.264 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 10
2024-05-22 14:52:37.265 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 11
2024-05-22 14:52:37.266 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 12


2024-05-22 14:52:37.269 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 1
2024-05-22 14:52:37.270 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 2
2024-05-22 14:52:37.270 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 3
2024-05-22 14:52:37.271 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 4
2024-05-22 14:52:37.272 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 5
2024-05-22 14:52:37.273 D/DBINFO_MNTH5: ID is 1 D1 is 1716353557183 D1(formatted) is 2024-05-22 14:52:37.183
2024-05-22 14:52:37.274 D/DBINFO_MNTH5: ID is 2 D1 is 1716353657235 D1(formatted) is 2024-05-22 14:54:17.235
2024-05-22 14:52:37.274 D/DBINFO_MNTH5: ID is 3 D1 is 1747889557236 D1(formatted) is 2025-05-22 14:52:37.236
2024-05-22 14:52:37.274 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 6
2024-05-22 14:52:37.275 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 7
2024-05-22 14:52:37.276 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 8
2024-05-22 14:52:37.277 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 9
2024-05-22 14:52:37.278 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 10
2024-05-22 14:52:37.280 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 11
2024-05-22 14:52:37.281 D/DBINFO: Processing Month 12


as can be seen the query as per the answer locates the 3 rows when  the respective month (05 being this month) is processed.
note that the future row for 2025 is extracted

Using App Inspection the data in the database can be seen to be:-

Also using App Inspection and a New Query the following can be used  that details some of the results as the points discussed (and shows a potentially useful debug methodology):-
Using the query:-
SELECT *, datetime(d1 / 1000) AS d1_a, datetime(d1 / 1000,'unixepoch'), typeof(d1), typeof(strftime('%m',d1 / 1000,'unixepoch')) AS d1_type, strftime('%m',d1 / 1000,'unixepoch') = 5 AS d1_compareA, CAST(strftime('%m',d1 / 1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER) = 5 AS d1_compareB FROM thetable


